# How to style the paper of a Drawer in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

The Material-UI update [MUI 5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#styles) advices to stop using `makeStyles` to define styles. It is recommended to use [emotion css](https://emotion.sh/). I wonder how to style the paper element of the [drawer](https://mui.com/components/drawers/) component. My goal is to handover a custom width to the paper element. How can I define a proper css-class?

[Drawer sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/temporarydrawer-material-demo-forked-uwedx?file=/demo.js)

**Old way** with `makeStyles`:

```
<Drawer
  classes={{
    paper: classes.paper,
  }}
  variant="persistent"
  anchor={anchor}
  open={isOpen}
>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about using the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) prop:

```
<Drawer
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      width: 100
    }
  }}
```

In case you want to style a nested component without `XxProps`:

```
<Drawer
  sx={{
    "& .MuiPaper-root": {
      width: 100
    }
  }}
```

If you don't want hardcode class name string:

```
import { paperClasses } from "@mui/material/Paper";
```

```
<Drawer
  sx={{
    [`& .${paperClasses.root}`]: {
      width: 100
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:** If you also want the Drawer's width to be [responsive](https://mui.com/system/basics/#responsive-values):

```
<Drawer
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      width: {
        xs: 300,
        sm: 500
      }
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Can I also add media-queries like in makeStyle-classes?

Comment: @vuvu you want something like [this](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries) in v5?

Comment: 10 stars response !